# GoogleAccountCredential chooseAccountIntent

Tags: android, google-api

I'm trying to start a choose account dialog with an intent, I get through `GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent`.

When I compile my source, an error `NoClassDefFoundError` occured.

Here is my error log:

```
12-18 09:55:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(25809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 09:55:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(25809): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker
12-18 09:55:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(25809):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(GoogleAccountCredential.java:171)
12-18 09:55:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(25809):    at com.arcticcoding.study.OverView.onCreate(OverView.java:67)
12-18 09:55:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(25809):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-18 09:55:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(25809):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
```

Comment: Does your device have Google Play Services installed? You need to check if it is installed before you try to use the Google Play Services API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the google play services library. I had the same issue
and resolved it here:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android with GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384236/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-android-with-googleaccountcredential-newchoose)

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle`, add this code to dependencies:

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```